# Rails + Postgres Relation Issue With Custom Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, foreign-key-relationship

I'm in the middle of a migration to Postgres from MySQL and i'v hit an issue that I just can't solve.  I'm sure there is simple answer, but i'm stuck.

**The Problem**

I have a **step** model that belongs to a **template** model, but specifies a foreign key called **template_uuid** to match on the template tables **uuid** column.

This all worked fine on MySQL but now does not work on Postgres.  Calling **step.template** would return the relevant template but now it returns nil

Both the uuid column on the template table and the template_uuid column on the step are UUID data types.

**Example:**

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to    :template, :foreign_key => :template_uuid
```

So, I get nil when trying to call the association

```
step = Step.last
step.template  => nil
```

But, I can query for the template using the template_uuid column, and it works just fine

```
Template.where(:uuid => step.template_uuid).first
```

So .. What am I missing here. The records and UUID's clearly line up so why does this relationship break now that i'm using Postgres.  There is no physical foreign key on the database, but that's never mattered before.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say why it worked before, but as long as you have also a custom primary_key on the associated model (other than :id), you have to provide that either

```
  belongs_to :template, :primary_key => :uuid, :foreign_key => :template_uuid
```

Comment: That did it.  Thank you!  I knew it had to be something small like that